# When can the relation $\frac{T2}{T1}= \left( \frac{P_2}{P_1}\right)^ {(r-1/r)}$ be used in case of a nozzle?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, energy, aerodynamics

> Air enters an adiabatic nozzle at 300 kPa, 500 K with a velocity of 10 m/s. It leaves the nozzle at 100 kPa with a velocity of 180 m/s. The inlet area is 80 cm2. The specific heat of air Cp is 1008 J/kg·K. What is the exit temperature of the air?

The following numerical was solved using steady flow energy equation to obtain an exit temperature of 483.98K. 
Why am i not getting the same value when i used the adiabatic relation  $\frac{T2}{T1}= \left( \frac{P_2}{P_1}\right)^{(r-1/r)}$ ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The adiabatic relation for the ideal gas has the assumption that all of the energy is internal

$$U=C_VT,$$
while your example clearly has collective kinetic energy, and then Bernoulli's law should apply instead

$$\frac{1}{2}\rho v^2+c_pT=\text{const}.$$

Comment: but how come the relation is used for isentropic flow through a compressor or turbine in a Brayton Cycle?